# Rewriting the query in better optimized way

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, where-clause

I have a bigger query in which when I use `outbreak_info_id in (80106)` as where condition
it results me in 2 secs .

Since I need to get some more relevant data , so I need to replace the above `where` condition with below where condition .

When I put the below `where` condition in the same query , it gives me results in ~30 secs.

Could someone please help to rewrite the below `where` condition in better way so that it executes in faster manner .

I can only think of what I wrote below .

**Expected** : To rewrite the below query in better way ,

```html
select distinct outbreak_info_id from outbreak_infos 
where outbreak_id 
IN (
select distinct ofe.outbreak_id  from 
outbreaks_for_events ofe
         inner join reports_infos ri on ofe.report_id=ri.report_id
        where  ofe.report_id in ( select distinct report_id from
         outbreaks_for_events oe where outbreak_id in ( 
              select distinct outbreak_id from outbreak_infos 
              where outbreak_info_id in (80106)))
    and ri.status='Validated')
```

Comment: The `distinct` inside the sub-selects for an IN clause is useless.

Comment: Your query has 4 where clauses.  Please show us the actual 2-sec query.